# How can I recover my tables in sql server database

Tags: sql-server

I deleted 3 tables from my database with data and I have no backup. How can I restore tables with data in my database ?

How can I restore tables and data with database log file?(Database recovery model is full)

Comment: If Database recovery model is full but you have *never* taken a backup it is in auto truncate mode. See [When is FULL Recovery not Really FULL Recovery](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2008/11/30/when-is-full-recovery-not-really-full-recovery.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as Iren and Rahul said, you can use ApexSQL tools. If the tables were dropped, [ApexSQL Recover](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_recover.aspx) can recover them even from databases in the simple recovery model. ApexSQL Recover can recover both table structure and table records

On the other hand, [ApexSQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx) cannot recover records lost when a table was dropped, it can only recover the table structure

In case the records that were lost using `DELETE` (not `DROP TABLE`), both ApexSQL Log and ApexSQL Recover can help

The advantages of ApexSQL tools over recovery to a point in time is that ApexSQL will recover just the tables you specify (creates `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` scripts) , while a point-in-time recovery will roll back all the transactions that happened in the meantime

A DROP TABLE statement marks the MDF file pages used by the dropped table for deallocation. These pages are actually still in the MDF file until overwritten by new operations. To prevent new operations overwrite the data necessary for successful recovery, we recommend creating a copy of the original MDF and LDF files immediately

*Disclaimer: I work for ApexSQL as a Support Engineer*

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would have to perform a point-in-time recovery of the database, this guide should help: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190982(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try using ApexSQL Recover to recover lost data due to drop without backup
http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/rollback-drop-table-statement-without-backups/

Answer (score -1):

You try this links ans get your solution

http://www.sqlrecoverytool.com/deleted-sql-records-recovery.html

http://apex-sql-log.apex-sql-llc.qarchive.org/